# autocomplete hov to using source function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have autocoplete code:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'autocomplete.txt',
        dataType: "json",
        data:
        {
            term: request.term,
        },
        success: function (data)
        {
            response(data);
        }       
    });     
},
minLength: 2,
select: function (event, ui)
{
    var test = ui.item ? ui.item.id : 0;
    if (test > 0)
    {
       alert(test);
    }
}   
});
```

there is the contents of the autocomplete.txt file:

```
["id":"100","value":"ActionScript","label":"ActionScript","desc":"ActionScript"},{"id":"200","value":"AppleScript","label":"AppleScript","desc":"AppleScript"},{"id":"300","value":"Asp","label":"Asp","desc":"Asp"},{"id":"400","value":"BASIC","label":"BASIC","desc":"BASIC"}]
```

When I type any characters into my input field, in result I get full list of 'autocomplete.txt' contents, not just words with matching characters. When I use this code:

```
var availableTags=[{"id":"100","value":"ActionScript","label":"ActionScript","desc":"ActionScript"},     
{"id":"200","value":"AppleScript","label":"AppleScript","desc":"AppleScript"},     {"id":"300","value":"Asp","label":"Asp","desc":"Asp"},    {"id":"400","value":"BASIC","label":"BASIC","desc":"BASIC"}];

$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags,
minLength: 2,
select: function (event, ui)
{
    var test = ui.item ? ui.item.id : 0;
    if (test > 0)
    {
       alert(test);
    }
}
```

everything is Ok, autocomplete only searches for matching words. Why doesn't properly work with the 'autocomplete.txt' file ?

Comment: I have no experience with jquery-ui-autocomplete, but your autocomplete.txt content has a typo you are missing the opening bracket "{" of the first element, maybe that is the issue

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this is my mistake in writting post. Original autocomplete.txt is with "{" bracket at the beginning of the first element : [{"id":"100","value":"ActionScript",...

Comment: I have found solution in documentation: "...String: When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the same host or on a different one (must support CORS). **The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results**, instead a query string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results...."